# Running bash script without asking for password

Tags: terminal, bash, password

I wrote a little shell script that switches some settings that I have to switch a lot. I saved it as a .command file, so double-clicking will run it. Now everytime I run it, it's asking for my password (although just changing those settings doesn't require any password when I do it by hand).
Is it possible to make the bash script run, without it asking for a password everytime? All it does is switches my proxy settings off...

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'quit app "MyAppsAnywhere"'
networksetup -setautoproxystate Wi-Fi off
exit 0
```

Comment: Try using `sudo networksetup ...` -- it will still ask for your password, just not every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
sudo networksetup -setautoproxystate Wi-Fi off
```

and then configure `sudoers(5)` to allow that exact command (or any `networksetup` invocation (or any command whatsoever)) without a password, though this generally requires fiddling around with `visudo(8)` and if you get things wrong may lock you out of future use of `sudo(1)`. Open a root shell, make a backup of `/etc/sudoers`, edit the file by running `visudo`, test it, and use root shell to restore the backup of the config if things go awry. Relevant `sudoers(5)` config lines would be along the lines of

```
# only with these args
yourloginnamehere ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup-setautoproxystate Wi-Fi off, /usr/sbin/networksetup-setautoproxystate Wi-Fi on

# any arguments to the command
yourloginnamehere ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup

# no password prompts at all from sudo ever
yourloginnamehere  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Also `visudo` may run a strange editor by default, so you might want to read up on the `EDITOR` and `DISPLAY` environment variables and related `sudo` questions and documentation before you get stuck in `vi`...